# is it possible to write this mysql statement in a better way? cleanere? more readable? faster?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, users and results.

Results contains column `user_id` same as users table.

I want to grab results table, sum results_value column, and than use user_id to grab additional info from users table.... I came up with this:

```
SELECT results.user_id, SUM(results.result_value), users.user_name, users.user_pic, users.user_level 
FROM results, users 
WHERE users.user_id = results.user_id 
GROUP BY results.user_id 
ORDER BY SUM(results.result_value) DESC
LIMIT 4
```

It actually works, but being a complete mysql beginner, I'm wondering if I'm doing something stupid, or maybe it works but there is a better way (faster) way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is actually fine. It is possible to write it without `GROUP BY`, it is probably easier to understand:

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    (   SELECT sum(r.result_value)
        FROM results r
        WHERE r.user_id = u.user_id
    ) AS rsum,
    u.user_name,
    u.user_pic,
    u.user_level
FROM users u
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 4
```

As you may notice, using table aliases helps a lot with readability of your queries.

Comment: Why order by 2? what does that mean?

Comment: It simply means `ORDER BY` column number `2` in `SELECT` list - must shorter way to write `ORDER BY <that_long_expression> DESC`

Comment: Is isn't it easier in your case to just write: order by rsum? Anyways, thanks for your help... this is my new style of writing sql statements, vs my one liners :P

Comment: Can you please help me also with question: @15256041?

Comment: Depending on the version of mysql, using subselects like this can be massively slower than using group by.

Comment: If mysql is 5.1 or more, it should not make measurable difference. And you should not be running anything less than 5.1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Basics look fine. Main thing is to make sure you have suitable indexes. Also you should have all the non aggregate columns named in the GROUP BY clause (not 100% necessary in MySQL, but is in some other flavours of SQL, and not doing this can result in indeterminate values being returned for those columns).

You can also do the JOIN using more modern syntax:-

```
SELECT results.user_id, SUM(results.result_value) AS Asum, users.user_name, users.user_pic, users.user_level 
FROM results
INNER JOIN users 
ON users.user_id = results.user_id 
GROUP BY results.user_id, users.user_name, users.user_pic, users.user_level 
ORDER BY Asum DESC
LIMIT 4
```